# How to stop responding the intent filter in Android

Tags: android

I have added intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml file in the following way,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
       android:scheme="upi"
       android:host="pay" />
</intent-filter>
```

And suppose the intent call initiated from the merchant end and I want, this mobile app should not be listed from the installed apps list for the below scenario:

> The customer not registered and just downloaded app from the playstore.

So, please suggest me how shall I add above intent filter dynamically from android activity?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an activity which has the intent filter: You can enable or disable the activity:

You can disable it by default in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:enabled="false"
    ...>
    <intent-filter ... />
</activity>
```

To enable it programmatically:

```
val componentName = ComponentName(context.applicationContext, MyActivity::class.java)
context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        componentName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

To disable it programmatically:

```
context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        componentName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

Reference: `setComponentEnabledSetting` documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)